# Different A records for a domain

Tags: dns, ip

I have a domain which A record points to a site, hosted on VPS.
Now I want to make a mail server, which is located on a second VPS. To make mail server work I need MX records, which is based on A record. So my DNS should look like this:

Name | Type | IP

Site ---- A - First_VPS_IP
 Mail --- A -- Second_VPS_IP
 @ ----- MX - Mail

But clearly, it is impossible to create two different A records. So is it possible to use different servers for site and mail server on same domain? Thanks.

Comment: If you expect meaning answers, you would better document your current setup in more detail.

Comment: You need another A record, but for subdomain. Call it `mail.yourname.yourtld`, and set MX record of to point to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly possible. It's a matter of what DNS you're using or who hosts it. Below is a (very) shortened version of my zone.

```
                IN      MX      100     mx.bromosapien.net.
mailer          IN      A       69.7.19.205
healer          IN      A       69.7.19.204
```

You can see that "healer" and "mx" (my mail server) have two different A records. My MX record is pointing to my A record. My blank label means last label or origin. My origin, in this case, is bromosapien.net. I suggest using a blank label for your MX record if you're using bind.

Everything needs an A record. It's not "impossible" to have two different A records.

Comment: Looks like you are right. And it is quite strange, that tech support of my dns service did not allow me to do so. Well, going to change it I guess. Thank you anyway!